# How do I delegate authentication to external API server?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have two environments:

- *A*: Laravel-based application API server
  (I have full permission for this)
- *B*: External API server for *A*
  (I don't have permission to access user without his/her authentication)

`users` table has only two columns, `id` and `external_user_id`. `id` is created by *A* and `external_user_id` is created by *B*.

If I implement a custom provider, I need to follow two contracts:

```
<?php

interface UserProvider
{
    public function retrieveById($identifier);
    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token);
    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token);
    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials);
    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials);
}

interface Authenticatable
{
    public function getAuthIdentifierName();
    public function getAuthIdentifier();
    public function getAuthPassword();
    public function getRememberToken();
    public function setRememberToken($value);
    public function getRememberTokenName();
}
```

However, there is a very difficult problem: How do I call `retrieveByCredentials()` before verifying user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Throw `BadMethodCallException` on every method
- Never use `Auth::attempt()`
- Only use `Auth::login()`

```
<?php

class MyUserProvider extends Provider implements UserProvider
{
    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException();
    }
    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException();
    }
    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException();
    }
    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException();
    }
    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException();
    }
}

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException();
    }
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException();
    }
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException();
    }
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException();
    }
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException();
    }
    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException();
    }
}
```